# Reference class libar from .NET Core Console

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am migrating to .NET Core 2.0 from .NET Core 1.1. The WebAPI project is working fine with references to .NET Standard 2.0 class libaries. However my test projects which are change to .NET Core 2.0 app also are not seeing .NET Standard 2.0 class libaries.

I am readding reference to these class libaries but error appears : could not font type ....

Answer (score 2):

Try to create new test libraries(2.0 standard) from scratch and move unit tests into new libs (it can save you a lot of time).